# UINavigationBar wrong position in Landscape start

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

iPad app.  I have a tabbar. One tab has a view controller with a view.  In that view controller I add a uinavigationcontroller.  If I start the app in portrait, everything works fine.  However if the app starts in landscape, my navbar y position is 20 (instead of 0 which it should be). I can see the view behind the navbar.  If I manually re-position (a bandaid) the uinavigationcontroller to -20 y, I get a host of sizing problems throughout the app.  How can I fix this?  (by the way, if i remove the status bar it sizes just fine in landscape)

[image]

Here is the code of my view that manages the navcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.topicsList = [[TopicsListVC alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.topicsList];

self.navController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.navController.view];
```